# /dev/ttyS0 does not open in ubuntu 12.04 beta

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 beta.
I premit that minicom works properly on /dev/ttyS0 (but putty doesn't).
I control the port in C code which works properly on ubuntu 11.10:

```
fd = open(p_ttys_parms->device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(fd < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR: cannot open device %s\n", p_ttys_parms->device);
    return 0;
}
```

but in 12.04 beta I get fd < 0 and exit after the printf.
Did anybody experience the same and succeeded somehow?

Comment: And what is in `errno`? That should be the _first_ thing you look at.

Comment: I get errno: Permission denied, running it again with sudo it works. You solved my problem thank you (even if I don't get the reason why in 12.04 I need sudo to open a serial port while in 11.10 it was not necessary).

Comment: No probs, I'll copy that to an answer and add some more detail on the likely reason and fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing you should do is check the value of `errno`. The `open` call, if it returns -1, will set `errno` to a value indicating what the actual problem is.

---

And, based on your comment that it's `Permission denied` and your program works when run under `sudo`, it's probably a permissions problem with the `/dev/ttyS0` device file.

I get a similar issue under Debian 6:

```
pax> ls -al /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Mar 23 21:00 /dev/ttyS0
pax> echo xyzzy >/dev/ttyS0
bash: /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied
```

You may find you need to add your user to the `dialout` group (or another group, depending on how far Ubuntu deviates from my beloved Debian) to be allowed access:

```
pax> id -Gn
pax cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth scanner

pax> sudo adduser pax dialout
[sudo] password for pax: 
Adding user pax to group dialout
Done.

<< Restart done here to ensure new group picked up >>

pax> id -Gn
pax dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth scanner
```

Comment: yes it worked for mee too, thank you very much (sudo usermod -a -G dialout myusername ; sudo shutdown -r 0)

Comment: No need to "restart".  The `pax` user just needs to log out and back in again.

Answer (score 1):

I used following command to set perminssion (i'm using `/dev/ttyUSB0`).

```
sudo chmod 0777 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

When i execute the command:

```
 AvailableSerialPorts: {'/dev/ttyUSB0'}
       JarFileVersion: 'Version 2.11.0'
ObjectConstructorName: {'serial('/dev/ttyUSB0');'}
          SerialPorts: {'/dev/ttyUSB0'}
```

And also, I've opened matlab with root permission (in terminal).

```
sudo /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/matlab
```

Comment: Thank you, but this works for only one serial device... I think adding the user to the group dialout is a better solution